# Formatting CSV file created using pypyodbc

Tags: python, sql, format, writer, pypyodbc

I'm using the following code to query a SQL Server DB, and storing the returned results in a CSV file.

```
import pypyodbc 
import csv

connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                            'Server=localhost;'
                            'Database=testdb;') 
cursor = connection.cursor()

SQLCommand = (""" SELECT A as First,
                  SELECT B as Second,
                  FROM AB """)

cursor.execute(SQLCommand) 
results = cursor.fetchall() 

myfile = open('test.csv', 'w')
wr = csv.writer(myfile,dialect='excel')
wr.writerow(results)

connection.close()
```

The SQL command is just a sample, my query contains a lot more columns, this is just for example sake.

With this code, my CSV looks like this:

[image]

But I want my CSV to look like so, and plus I want the headers to show as well, like this:
[image]

I'm guessing the formatting needs to be done within the 'csv.writer' part of the code but I cant seem to figure it out. Can someone please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing that strange output because `fetchall` returns multiple rows of output but you are using `writerow` instead of `writerows` to dump them out. You need to use `writerow` to output a single line of column headings, followed by `writerows` to output the actual results:

```python
with open(r'C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\test.csv', 'w', newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    wr.writerow([x[0] for x in cursor.description])  # column headings
    wr.writerows(cursor.fetchall())
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```